# How to mount WDMyCloud to Ubuntu Server via terminal

Tags: networking, mount, ssh, cifs

So a little context first. I'm a first time linux server user :) never tried it before but I'm slowly getting the hang of things. Still learning my way around syntax and the terminal. I'm trying to run plex off of my linux server but most of my media content is on my WDMyCloud. So I'm trying to mount my WDMyCloud public drive to a folder on my linux machine so that I can then link the plex library to that folder.

I found this tutorial : [Mounting the WD MyCloud on Ubuntu 20](https://programmingwithjim.wordpress.com/2021/03/01/mounting-the-wd-mycloud-on-ubuntu-20/) and I followed it. I got as far as step 4 in the public shared section. But when I tried to do the following code:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0 //<*my MyCloud IP address*>  /media/public
```

It would ask for `Password for @root//<*my MyCloud IP address*> (press TAB for no echo)` , I turned on SSH on the MyCloud and set a password and typed in the same. But even if I had SSH off and just hit enter I get:

```
[518.952125] CIFS VFS: Malformed UNC in devname
mount error(22): Invalid argument UNC in devname.
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cif) and kernal log messages (dmesg)
```

What am I doing wrong? am I missing somthing?

Comment: Been a while since I did this, but I think you need to add the name of the WD share to your WD host.. //<*my MyCloud IP address*>/media.